# Why apache find files on system root directory instead of project directory, I got error like FileNotFound

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, file-not-found

Apache does not find files on my project directory which is `/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis` but they find files/directories on system root `'/'`

when I hint the URL `http://<server IP:5000>`

The Apache get the error `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292029 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876] ERROR:main:Exception on / [GET]
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292060 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292064 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292068 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292071 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292075 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292078 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292081 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292084 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292094 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     raise value
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292097 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292100 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292102 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292105 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292108 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/main.py", line 147, in student
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292111 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     thumbnail_list, _ = load_video_with_thumbnail()
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292114 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/functions.py", line 87, in load_video_with_thumbnail
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292117 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     for file in pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath('Processed_Tasks').iterdir():
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292120 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1081, in iterdir
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292123 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292125 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292128 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]     return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292133 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Processed_Tasks'
[Mon May 18 09:14:42.292139 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 16418:tid 140427906770688] [client 103.104.192.170:43876]
```

`Processed_Tasks/` already exist in my project directory

here my project structure :

```
web_app_video_synopsis/
├── Downloaded_Thumbnail
├── Downloaded_Video
├── Processed_Tasks
├── Processed_Videos
├── Queue
├── README.md
├── centroid_tracker
├── database
├── functions.py
├── main.py
├── preprocessing.py  
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── templates
├── web_app_video_synopsis.wsgi
└── yolact_segmentation
```

Project configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web_app_video_synopsis.conf`:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/www/web_app_video_synopsis

<VirtualHost *:5000>
            ServerName http://<Server IP>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/web_app_video_synopsis.wsgi
            WSGIDaemonProcess web_app_video_synopsis python-path=/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
            WSGIProcessGroup web_app_video_synopsis
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            <Directory /var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/static
            <Directory /var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`web_app_video_synopsis.wsgi` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
import os

#activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/bin/activate_this.py'
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/bin/activate_this.py")
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/")

from main import app as application
```

Error produce these lines in my code `functions.py`

```
    for file in pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath('Processed_Tasks').iterdir():
        with open(file, mode='r') as f:
            task_data = json.load(f)
```

In the local machine, the current working directory is the same where the `main.py` located in the project directory

So How I access(read/write/execute) files from `/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis` ?

Like my code, many files read and write in the project directory.

**Solution**

`web_app_video_synopsis.wsgi` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
import os

#activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/bin/activate_this.py'
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pytorch/bin/activate_this.py")
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis/")
os.chdir("/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis")

from main import app as application
```

must set project directory using `os.chdir`

Comment: WSGIPythonPath /var/www/www/web_app_video_synopsis


www is 2 times ?

Comment: @MuhammadAamir So you say remove from either one. I got the same error, either remove first one or last one in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web_app_video_synopsis.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, just add 
`os.chdir("/var/www/web_app_video_synopsis")` in `web_app_video_synopsis.wsgi` and project directory set. I also edit my question with solution